# React, TS, Code Splitting, Webpack : how to

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, code-splitting

i have a monolithic application, created with CRA. Its works with Typescript and contains different business modules with 1 folder for each one (ex: modules/module-1 modules/module-2). I'd like to make this modules usable as npm packages.

I struggle to understand how to do this. Does anyone has example ?

Each modules has to expose some routes leading to the business pages. And a core module need to exposes components, types, hooks, providers...

I can't figure out how to build each my packages.

I already have a npm registry on my gitlab and know how to publish packages on it.

I tried to build the core module with react-scripts without any webpack config file but it gives me an error at "yarn build" :

`Could not find a required file. Name: index.html`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.